# ReplaceAll not working on String[] element

Tags: java, replaceall

I need to write chess programm that uses FEN as an argument for creating a chess board. To simplyfy the process I want to replace number with equal amount of "1"  to that number with replaceAll method (look my code). Unfortunately this doesn't work and I don't know know why. Can somebody please tell me what I should do differently?

```
String[] read2 = new String[] {"rnbqkbnr", "pppppppp", "8", "8", "8", "8", "PPPPPPPP", "RNBQKBNR"};         
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(read2[i]);
    read2[i].replaceAll("8", "11111111");
    read2[i].replaceAll("7", "1111111");
    read2[i].replaceAll("6", "111111");
    read2[i].replaceAll("5", "11111");
    read2[i].replaceAll("4", "1111");
    read2[i].replaceAll("3", "111");
    read2[i].replaceAll("2", "11");
    System.out.println(read2[i]);   
}
```

The output is

```
rnbqkbnr
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
pppppppp
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
PPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
RNBQKBNR
```

but should be

```
rnbqkbnr
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp
pppppppp
8
11111111
8
11111111
8
11111111
8
11111111
PPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
RNBQKBNR
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is a function that return an string. You should store the value replaced somewhere, for example in `read2[i]`

Comment: BTW according to your login your output would NOT be `pppppppp 8 11111111` because that `8` would be replaced.

Comment: @bradbury9 he is printing the values before updating them.

Comment: @Akhadra before closing it he is printing it again.

Comment: @bradbury9 he mentioned in the post the second results are what he want but not showing and that's why he was wondering.

Comment: @Akhadra Int the output there would be no `8` because of `read2[i] = read2[i].replace("8", "11111111");` and OP says it shoud be `pppppppp *8* 11111111 *8* 11111111 8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save results in your array to replace old value with new value, you are generating a new string by calling the replace on the existing string and you are not assigning the new string to the object reference.

```
 String[] read2 = new String[] {"rnbqkbnr", "pppppppp", "8", "8", "8", "8", "PPPPPPPP", "RNBQKBNR"};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {

    System.out.println(read2[i]);
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("8", "11111111");
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("7", "1111111");
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("6", "111111");
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("5", "11111");
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("4", "1111");
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("3", "111");
    read2[i] = read2[i].replace("2", "11");
    System.out.println(read2[i]);

}
```

Edit: As suggested in the comments use replace instead of replaceAll because replaceAll is used for Regular expressions.

Comment: Might as well explain why